# Firebase User not updating after displayname is changed

Tags: swiftui

I have created a ProfileView where users can update their user's displayName and photoURL. The ProfileView detects when a user has updated a displayName in and provides a save button in the UI. After the save button is clicked `updateDisplayName()` is called which updates the displayName attached to the user.

The issue I have encountered is that the MenuView which provides the NavigationView that leads to the ProfileView never gets updated. However, In other views I have that write to Firestore the updated displayName is successfully being pulled out of my authVM EnvironmentObject. Its odd that other views are seeing the updated user where as MenuView never gets updated. To me it indicates that the User is being updated properly, but for some reason MenuView isn't pulling the newly update User data.The same behavior is seen with the photoURL, but keeping the discussion to the displayName to keep things less verbose.

Any ideas why this view doesn't see the updated user data and how I could go about fixing it?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import Resolver

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    @Published var signedIn: Bool = false
    @Published var showError: Bool = false
    @Published var errorText: String = ""
    @Published var showPasswordAlert: Bool = false
    @Published var user: User?
    private var authenticationStateHandler: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    init() {
        addListeners()
      }
    
    private func addListeners() {
        if let handle = authenticationStateHandler {
          Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }

        authenticationStateHandler = Auth.auth()
          .addStateDidChangeListener { _, user in
            self.user = user
          }
      }

func updateDisplayName(displayName: String) {
        let changeRequest = self.auth.currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
        changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { err in
            if let err = err {
                
            }
            self.auth.currentUser?.reload(completion: { err in
                if let err = err {
                    
                }
                print(self.auth.currentUser?.displayName)
            })
        })
        self.auth.currentUser?.reload()
    }
    
    func updatePhotoURL(photoURL: URL) {
        print(self.auth.currentUser?.photoURL)
        let changeRequest = self.auth.currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest?.photoURL = photoURL
        changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { err in
            if let err = err {
                
            }
            self.auth.currentUser?.reload(completion: { err in
                if let err = err {
                    
                }
                print(self.auth.currentUser?.photoURL)
            })
        })
        self.auth.currentUser?.reload()
    }
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Resolver
import FirebaseAuth

struct MenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authVM: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {

            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        ProfileRowView(url: authVM.user?.photoURL, memberName: authVM.user?.displayName ?? "")
                }.listStyle(.plain)
                
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"))
               
            }
    }
}

struct ProfileRowView: View {
    var url: URL?
    var memberName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView()) {
            HStack{
                AttendeeImage(url: url)
                Text(memberName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ProfileView**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {
    @StateObject var profileVM = ProfileViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            VStack {
                ProfileHeaderView(profileVM: profileVM)
                ProfileText(profileVM: profileVM)
                Spacer()
                ProfileSaveButton(profileVM: profileVM)
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .sheet(isPresented: $profileVM.showPicker) {
                ImagePicker(sourceType: profileVM.source == .library ? .photoLibrary : .camera, selectedImage: $profileVM.image, isImageSelected: $profileVM.isImageSelected)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .alert("Error", isPresented: $profileVM.showCameraAlert, presenting: profileVM.cameraError, actions: { cameraError in
                cameraError.button
            }, message: { cameraError in
                Text(cameraError.message)
            })
        }
    }
}



struct ProfileText: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authVM: AuthViewModel
    @ObservedObject var profileVM: ProfileViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(
                "Display Name",
                text: $profileVM.displayName
            )
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
            self.profileVM.setDisplayName(displayName: authVM.user?.displayName ?? "")
        }
        .onChange(of: profileVM.displayName) {
            if ($0 != "" && $0 != authVM.user?.displayName ?? "") {
                withAnimation { profileVM.isNewDisplayName = true }
            } else {
                withAnimation { profileVM.isNewDisplayName = false }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileSaveButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authVM: AuthViewModel
    @ObservedObject var profileVM: ProfileViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        // Check if displayName has changed or an image has been uploaded
        if profileVM.isNewDisplayName || profileVM.isImageSelected {
            Button {
                if profileVM.isNewDisplayName {
                    authVM.updateDisplayName(displayName: profileVM.displayName)
                    profileVM.isNewDisplayName = false
                }
                if profileVM.isImageSelected {
                    profileVM.saveProPic(userId: authVM.user?.uid ?? "", completion: { downloadUrl in
                        if let downloadUrl = downloadUrl {
                            authVM.updatePhotoURL(photoURL: downloadUrl)
                            profileVM.isImageSelected = false
                        } else {
                            //handle nil response
                        }
                    })
                }
            } label: {
                ButtonLabel(symbolName: "person.crop.circle.badge.checkmark", label: "Save")
            }
            .transition(.opacity)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```